# Tabulator JS 5 Apply Bootstrap JS 5 Dark Theme

Tags: bootstrap-5, tabulator

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jbtopLuc/)

```
<div class="table-dark" id="table"></div>
```

```js
//Sample Data
var tableData = [
    {name:"Bob"},
    {name:"Steve"},
    {name:"Jim"},
]

//Example Table
var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
    data:tableData, //load data into table
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:200, editor:"input"},
    ]
});
```

[Tabulator JS 5 Docs for Bootstrap 5 Theme](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/theme#framework-boot5)
[Bootstrap JS 5 Docs for Table Variants](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/content/tables/#variants)

In the above Fiddle example, the "table-dark" is not being applied to the table. From the linked documentation, it should apply the styling. Note that the text color does change, however the background colors do not.

I've tried manually setting "table-dark" on the parent div and also on each row using the "rowFormatter". I've also tried using the "theme" attribute with "bootstrap5" when instantiating the table.

Comment: No, you need `table table-dark`.

Comment: The documentation does say otherwise though.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for the comments. I agree with your assessments. I also dug into the CSS and realized that there's nothing about "dark" themes. Instead, I had ChatGPT take in the bootstrap JS CSS and output the dark themed version CSS. With some tweaks, it seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator JS V5's Bootstrap V5 CSS does not include any "dark" theme CSS. The issue is the missing CSS and the Tabulator JS documentation is incorrect. To get around this, you can write your own "dark" CSS classes.

ChatGPT was able to take in the Bootstrap V5 CSS from Tabulator's documentation with a carefully curated prompt, it output just the CSS to change the colors for all of the "dark" theme classes. It will require some tweaks.